# Angular material button disable color change

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design

```
<button _ngcontent-pse-c676="" mat-icon-button="" class="mat-focus-indicator setting_button mat-icon-button mat-button-base ng-star-inserted mat-button-disabled" ng-reflect-disabled="true" disabled="true">
```

css

```
.setting_button { float: right; margin-right: 8px; bottom: 10px; }
```

how i change the button color if the status is disable?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css disabled pseudo-class:

```
.setting_button:disabled {
   background-color: red
}
```